# Ajax disconnects from C++ http server

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, xmlhttprequest

I've made myself a simple C++ application that streams data via HTTP. When I open the server IP and port in a browser, I can see the stream in the browser window. But any XHR requests made from browser to the C++ server are automatically closed from the client side right after receiving headers.
Using TELNET or PHP or even a browser without any scripts gives me the stream data without problems.
Connecting Ajax to PHP script that generates dummy stream works too.

What could be causing this problem?
Could it be caused by the first byte sent being '\0'?
Or could it be caused by the port used not being 80?

The C++ server and the PHP script are both running on the same Debian Linux machine.
The JS script has been tested in multiple browsers, including Opera, Mozzila Firefox and Chrome.

The server sends theese headers:

```
write(*con, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n",16);
write(*con, "X-Powered-By: Darker\n",21);
write(*con, "Pragma: no-cache\n",17);
write(*con, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n",42);
write(*con, "Connection: keep-alive\n",23);
```

OK, so with the help of the Wireshark and Opera DragonFly I have separated several problems, that occur:

- The "responseText" in the HTTPRequest is always "" (an empty string), although in the Wireshark I can easily see the data being received properly.
- The "readyState" is always 4 when receiving the response, even though the stream has not been ended from the server-side.

Comment: An AJAX request is a short request to get some data and nothing else, and probably uses a `Connection: close` header instead of `Connection: Keep-Alive`.

Comment: The PHP server sends keep-alive as well and it works.

Comment: How about dumping the traffic with some network sniffer, so that you can see what are the differences between your streaming daemon and the dummy PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate the content-length header indicating the exact size of your stream in bytes. Also, out of curiosity, are you streaming plain text (as indicated in your content type)? If yes, not having a content length could be the problem as the `\r\n\r\n` has a meaning in HTTP

Comment: Actually I don't think this is the problem, because I have checked the headers sent by the PHP server and there is no trace of `content-length`. As I said above, JavaScript communicates without problems with the PHP. I end the headers with `\r\n\r\n` properly.

Comment: it is not about encoding the headers - if your stream contains \r\n\r\n the browser will end reading the stream there (as CRLF have a special meaning in HTTP), and that's maybe your problem. Unless you specify a content-length (the browser will read content-length bytes), use multipart/form-data with boundaries (the browser will read everything between the boundaries) or encode the CRLF properly when sending as text/plain - see http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt

Comment: The stream does not contain any CRLF signs... Example of the stream: '\0[1,100]\0\0\0[2,304]\0\0[3,5]\0' and so on. And I don't want to use content-length, as I do not know the length of the content. But I am going to dig into this. Anyways thanks for your answers, I hope they will help me solve this out!

Comment: if you do not want to use content-length, then your best bet is to use multipart/form-data with boundaries - see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2